# How can I generate a click on a certain part of the page when the page loads?

Tags: javascript

Basically I want a certain spot on my page to be clicked when the visitor loads the page. I want this one click to happen without the user even clicking. Is it possible?

Comment: Why not just invoke whatever behavior you want to see?  Why do you have to specifically simulate a click?

Comment: Could you provide more info? What are you ultimately hoping to accomplish?

Comment: If you separate/structure your code properly, then you don't need a click and just run the code like @cdhowie said (unless you need specific event data).

Comment: One advantage I could see is analytics possibly?  Or code reuse by having to write the onload click handler as well as still letting the user click the element after the page loads?

Comment: Do you have access to the link you want to click? Do you want to click on some ads... ?

Comment: @jmort253: Code reuse is better achieved by putting all the logic in a function and let the click handler call that function.

Comment: @Felix - Depends on how much reuse you've planned I guess.  I'll update my answer to allow for this... EDIT:  On second thought... that will just look way too over-architected for this.  The idea is to keep it simple.  At least for this case.

Comment: No it's not for clicking ads or anything, one of my clients asked me to do something for them and it required something like this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<script type="text/javascript">    
   $(document).ready( function() {

      // target represents the id of the element you are wanting to be clicked.
      $('#target').click(function() {
         // your click handler logic goes here
      });

      // click the element for the user...
      $('#target').click();

   });
</script>


<div id="target">This is the element on the page that will be clicked on pageload</div>
```

**UPDATE:** This is using JQuery, which is a JavaScript library.  Here is a script tag you can use to import JQuery in your HEAD section, if you're not already using it:

```
  <head>
    ...
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    ...
  </head>
```

http://jquery.com/

Using a JavaScript library, such as JQuery, will ensure that this functionality works cross-browser.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, what in the question makes you think the OP is using jQuery?

Comment: @cdhowie - I've seen this guy around before.  The last question I answered for him was a JQuery question I believe.  Plus, he didn't really define specific requirements, so I chose what I consider to be the best tool for the job.

Comment: @jmort253: But maybe you should provide more context information then. Other people might come and looking for how to simulate clicks in *pure* JavaScript. And to them, your answer will look not useful.

Comment: @Andreyco - Care to elaborate as to why?  As long as the element is within the context of the DOM, it will work.

Comment: Just try it on your own...
This -> $('#target').click(); -> wont click #target for user... thats why it does not work... Run your code, to see you are wrong.

Comment: @Andreyco - Funny how it seems to work just fine.  Perhaps you're just doing it wrong.  Did you define some actions where it says "your click handler logic goes here", like alert('oh shucks, it looks like it does work after all!');

Answer (score 2):

If you want to achieve the same purpose without using a javascript library you can use the following code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
window.onload=function(){ //when the window loads
  var paragraph = document.getElementById("google"); //store the object into a
  // variable

  //set the functions that will fireup when click happens - not necessary - 
  //for example purposes
  paragraph.onclick = function(){ 
    this.style.background="red";
  }

  paragraph.onclick(); //simulate click
}
</script>

<p id="google">Google text</p>
```

**demo here:** http://jsfiddle.net/9azTR/2/

Comment: Did you test this in IE7 and IE8?

Comment: i just did for IE6, IE7, IE8 and IE9 on the adobe browser lab https://browserlab.adobe.com/ and it seems to work perfectly.

Comment: +1 - Awesome!  Nice job!  I just verified on IE7 on Windows XP.

Answer (score 0):

You can fire specified event on DOM ready. You can to that using jQuery...

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#clickme').bind('click', function() {
            alert('Here goes code you would like to perform');
            alert('And another pieco of code, if you wish');
        });
        $('#clickme').trigger('click');
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Agreed with @Felix Kling.  If you are trying to simulate a click from a user on an object you can just invoke the function.

But from the way the question was worded it sounds like you want to simulate a click on an ad to generate revenue on your site?  If so the DOM will not allow you to access another containing frame (e.g. an iframe) - that's a security violation.

If you want to that you would have to somehow hijack the user's mouse though an ActiveX control or other malicious means, which of course is unscrupulous.

Comment: And, of course, scripting behavior like this would probably be against the ad service's TOS.

Comment: No it's not for clicking ads or anything blackhat. I don't know anything about ActiveX so I guess this is just going to be something I can't do!